How to find root cause of MOUPG Compatibility: Uncategorized Block found? (Windows 11 24h2 upgrade issue)
I have PC with below configuration

Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
Version  10.0.22631 Build 22631
Processor    12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900KS, 3400 Mhz, 16
Core(s), 24 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date    American Megatrends Inc. 1720, 8/12/2022
BaseBoard Manufacturer   ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoard Product    ROG MAXIMUS Z690 HERO
Hardware Abstraction Layer   Version = "10.0.22621.2506"

And I want to upgrade to Windows 11 24h2 with Windows 11 Installation Assistance. But I see below error

This PC can't be upgraded to this version of Windows.
Your PC has a driver or service that isn't ready for this version of
Windows. Windows Update will automatically offer you this version of Windows once the issue has been resolved.

After I tried to found the problem, I found some problem in C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupAppraiser::StartScan (143):   Start Scan Done
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         ConX::Compatibility::CCompatibilityHost::SerializeData: Provider wsc:wica: is serializing 2214 bytes of data.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info       [0x090008] PANTHR CBlackboard::Open: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\CompatScanCache.dat succeeded.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info       [0x090009] PANTHR CBlackboard::Close: c:\$windows.~bt\sources\panther\compatscancache.dat.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         ConX::Compatibility::CCompatibilityHost::SetScanResult: Provider wsc:wica: reports HardBlock
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         ConX::Compatibility::CCompatibilityController::ReportData: Type: [0], ID: [3], ReportOption: [2]
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         Reporting block for Categories: 0x00000010 
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         ConX::Compatibility::CCompatibilityController::ReportData: Type: [0], ID: [9], ReportOption: [2]
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         Compatibility scan finished. Categories: 0x006f0018 
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         Compatibility scan data is saved to C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\CompatData_2024_12_27_13_00_08_006f0018.xml.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         Compatibility scan data is saved to C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\ScanResult.xml.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Saved InstallReq scan result at : C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\ScanResult.xml
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Compatibility: GenerateInstallReqCompatReports enter
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Compatibility: No error in scan
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Compatibility: Device Block found.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Compatibility: Device-Actionable Block NOT found.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Compatibility: Dismissible Block NOT found.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Compatibility: App Uninstall Block NOT found.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Compatibility: Uncategorized Block found.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         Compatibility scan data is saved to C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\ScanResult.xml.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Saved InstallReq scan result at : C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\ScanResult.xml
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Compatibility: Notify UI that HardBlock status has been updated.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         CSetupCompatDlpResponse::OnCompatResultsChanged: Regenerating compat report.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         [CreateReport] Generating report for scenario (3), report type (5).
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Compatibility: Hardblock found. InstallReq polling starts...
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  CInstallUI::ShowPage: Posted MSG_INSTALLUI_SWITCH_TO_RESPONSE_PAGE
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  CInstallUI::CInstallUIMessageWindow::SwitchToResponsePage
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  CInstallUI::SwitchToResponsePage
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                  MOUPG  Compatibility: Starting Wait
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         CSetupResponsePageCompat::OnInitDialog: Dialog initializing - InstallReq.
2024-12-27 13:00:08, Info                         CSetupResponsePageCompat::UpdateView: Updating report control.

As you can see my problem is MOUPG  Compatibility: Uncategorized Block found.  But I could not find any additional info about that.
My question is How to find what is service/driver/application cause the above problem?
Note: ScanResult is not show any problem
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<CompatReport xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/ApplicationExperience/UpgradeAdvisor/01012009" MigXmlFile="pULnITeVFUKdIoUg.999.11.5.0.0_APPRAISER_Migration.xml"><System X64Capable="True" X64Running="True"/><Hardware><HardwareItem HardwareType="Setup_BitlockerNoTargetSupport"><CompatibilityInfo BlockingType="None"/></HardwareItem><HardwareItem HardwareType="Setup_TargetIsNonStagedBuild"><CompatibilityInfo BlockingType="None"/></HardwareItem><HardwareItem HardwareType="Setup_LanguagePackDetected"><CompatibilityInfo BlockingType="None"/></HardwareItem><HardwareItem HardwareType="Setup_LicenseActivation"><CompatibilityInfo BlockingType="None"/></HardwareItem><HardwareItem HardwareType="Setup_FeaturesOnDemandDetected"><CompatibilityInfo BlockingType="None"/></HardwareItem><HardwareItem HardwareType="Setup_FlightSigningEnabled"><CompatibilityInfo BlockingType="None"/></HardwareItem><HardwareItem HardwareType="Setup_SecureBoot"><CompatibilityInfo BlockingType="None"/></HardwareItem><HardwareItem HardwareType="Generic">
            <CompatibilityInfo BlockingType="Hard" Message="Your PC has a driver or service that isn't ready for this version of Windows. Windows Update will automatically offer you this version of Windows once the issue has been resolved." Title="This PC can't be upgraded to this version of Windows."/>
            <Link Target="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2280120" Value="Learn More"/>
        </HardwareItem>
    </Hardware><SystemInfo UplevelEdition="Windows 11" OSMajorVersion="10" OSMinorVersion="0"/>
    <Devices/>
    <DriverPackages>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem98.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem11.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem64.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem90.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem101.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem80.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem10.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem4.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem7.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem44.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem99.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem102.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem67.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem65.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem57.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem50.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem71.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem56.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem106.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem16.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem76.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem52.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem20.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem85.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem58.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem91.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem61.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem51.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem78.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
        <DriverPackage Inf="oem34.inf" BlockMigration="False" HasSignedBinaries="True"/>
    </DriverPackages>
    <Programs/>
</CompatReport>


Update 12/28/2024 For more details based on some comments:
My system satisfy all Windows 11 requirements as you can see in below image:


Just checking the MS Target Link - it leads here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-24H2 - do you have anything installed in the list? (list of things that MS known could cause issue - and have made a Block/Hold to prevent you from updating to 24H2)

Unfortunately you will have to tell us if you match any of the criteria for the compatibility holds.

Do you have BitLocker enabled or disabled? We probably need CompatData_2024_12_27_13_00_08_006f0018.xml

ASUS is know for not supporting TPM 2.0 on “higher” quality product lines like the Maximus. I suspect the block might be related to TPM support hence the question about BitLocker.

My BitLocker is disabled, and I check with PC Health Check, and says everything is ok –

@Ramhound I copy all content in question for xml file, you can see in Note: ScanResult is not show any problem line

I see the ScanResults but not the file I believe might have the information I requested to diagnose your issue

Based on the SetupLogs.zip you submitted in this Microsoft Answers thread:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_11-wintop_update/windows-11-version-24h2-this-pc-cant-be-upgraded/6e20c717-c4f3-4817-a203-5578cc9ac12a
It's the Easy Anti-Cheat driver/service.
Please rename this folder:
c:\program files (x86)\easyanticheat
to "dummy"
Restart Windows and rerun 24H2 setup.
Reference:
Windows 11 ( Version 24H2 ) - This PC can't be upgraded to this - Microsoft Community:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_11-wintop_update/windows-11-version-24h2-this-pc-cant-be-upgraded/6e20c717-c4f3-4817-a203-5578cc9ac12a
